# Running ant file from its own directory

Tags: java, ant

I have a big ANT script that I use to build-up my environment: total-build.xml.
It calls a bunch of little build.xml files.

However, each of these build.xml files is designed to run in its directory.
For example:

```
(Project)Build: total-build.xml
(Project)A: build.xml
(Project)B: build.xml
(Project)C: build.xml
```

### total-build.xml looks a bit like:

```
<ant file="A\build.xml"/>
<ant file="B\build.xml"/>
<ant file="C\build.xml"/>
```

A\build.xml looks like this:

```
<copy dir="src" todir="dest"/>
```

That is, it contains relative paths assumed to be under A. In the example, I expect `src == A\src`.

I don't want to write absolute paths, as they make things inelegant.

So is there a way to tell ant to run the build.xml file from its own directory.

Suprisingly, I found nothing about this issue using google.

Comment: It would be useful if you can provide more details on how your `total-build.xml` file invokes the targets of other `build.xml` files.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the base dir property for the project tag of each build, like this:

```
<project name="main" default="help" basedir="..">

...

</project>
```

and use all relative paths.